# What does the expression int a {10}; do?

Tags: c++, initialization

I found an interesting expression `int a{10};` Seems it is similar to `int a(10);`. How does it work?

Answer (score 4):

It's the new [uniform initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization) syntax that is part of C++11